# unable to connect with pgsql. docker adding &quot; with hostname in pg_connect

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am running a php project with docker. `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` running successfully. but when I run my project in browser It gives me connection error
and in terminal I am getting below error.

> PHP Warning:  pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server:
> could not translate hostname `&quot;databaseHost&quot;` to address:
> Temporary failure in name resolution in 'path_of_file'

I am using below line to connect with db

```
$connection = pg_connect("host=databaseHost port=5432 dbname=dbname user=xxxx password=xxxx");
```

But I don't know why is it showing `&quot;` with the hostname.

Comment: Can you post your Compose file?

Comment: same configuration working fine for other colleagues. So I don't think it is composer.yml problem

Comment: My assumption is that it is. I think the `&quot;` is because browser is escaping quotes sent by application, and the real problem is that it cannot resolve `databaseHost` to an IP address. Are you able to connect to DB on `databaseHost:5432`?

Comment: yes. I am able to login in pgAdmin with docker and also run queries successfully. also `SELECT version();` returning me `PostgreSQL 9.5.25 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Debian 9.5.25-1.pgdg90+1), compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit`